# Multiple lassos not visible in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I'm trying to create a canvas that is split into 2 different sections with a small diagonal bar separating them. I tried using the Polygonal Lasso Tool but for some reason both lasso shapes won't appear simultaneously. Is there a different method and/or tool that must be used to achieve this?

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current result**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can have multiple selections but you cannot make multiple selections with the Polygonal Lasso tool.

Comment: [Sure you can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiCDT.gif) @AndrewH one simply needs to hold down the `Shift` key when starting a new selection, like all the lasso/marquee tools. (I think your method in the answer is better though)

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Trick is to let go of Shift after that first click. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your layers have the colored shape but the layer contains a white background so you will not see the layers below it. The basic steps are:

1. create a selection with the lasso tool and fill it with color.
2. Make a duplicate of that shape, flip it horizontal and flip it vertical.
3. Make a selection of the new shape and fill it with another color.
4. Then select both layers and scale to the edge of the canvas.

[image: Demo]

Another option for creating this layout

I would make the background black, then create a shape and add a stroke for the dividing line.

[image: option 2]